# How can I get get values of "0" and "1" as variables to a php page

Tags: php, ajax

I want to print values of "0" and "1" to print on a php page. in order to do that I want to know how to access this json object as a array. I have decoded it. but still unable to print it.

```
 {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "Data Received",
    "0": {
        "id": "385",
        "fname": "arriet ",
        "lname": "ephania ",
        "email": "amym@mator.com",
        "mob": "9877"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "386",
        "fname": "Kelly ",
        "lname": "Echo ",
        "email": "sacen@mailinator.com",
        "mob": "1111"
    }

 }
```

Comment: Please post the PHP code you have, not the data only.

Comment: Is this your code response or some kind of external API response?

Comment: Thank you.. problem was solved by  following answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use json_decode with a true flag to convert it into an array and then for each to loop over data inside it,

```
$arr = json_decode('
    {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "Data Received",
    "0": {
        "id": "385",
        "fname": "arriet ",
        "lname": "ephania ",
        "email": "amym@mator.com",
        "mob": "9877"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "386",
        "fname": "Kelly ",
        "lname": "Echo ",
        "email": "sacen@mailinator.com",
        "mob": "1111"
    }

 }
    ', true);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    // strict type check for key with integer values.
    if(intval($key) === $key){
        print_r($value);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/jtIfW).

Comment: Thank you. Your previous answer also was helpful. solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You use `extract()` function like this

```html
\extract($data, EXTR_OVERWRITE);
include $file;
```